# Obtain directory listing as variables for nested for loop to create html

Tags: bash

I have the following command:

```
$ ls -alt|head -30
```

which produces:

```
total 1891268

drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jul 24 03:03 Beenie Man - Blessed (1995) - [MP3-V0]
drwxrwxr-- 940 ikwyl6 http         69632 Jul 24 02:54 .
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 http          4096 Jul 21 05:38 Ratatat - Magnifique (2015) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jul 21 03:45 The Chemical Brothers - Born in the Echoes (2015) - CD V0
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jul 21 03:38 Wilco - Star Wars (2015) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jul 19 01:45 The Jon Spencer Blues Explosion - Freedom Tower - No Wave Dance Party 2015 - 2015 (WEB - MP3 - V0)
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:17 Kendrick Lamar - To Pimp A Butterfly (2015) - WEB V0
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:15 Atmosphere - Sad Clown Bad Dub I (1999) [MP3-192]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:15 Joel Plaskett- The Park Avenue Sobriety Test (2015) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:11 Buena Vista Social Club - 2015 - Lost And Found [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:08 Florence + The Machine - How Big, How Blue, How Beautiful (Deluxe Edition) (2015) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:08 The Prodigy - The Day Is My Enemy [2015](V0)
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:07 Death Cab For Cutie - Kintsugi (2015) - WEB V0
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:07 Sufjan Stevens - Carrie & Lowell (2015) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 17:02 Aesop Rock-Cat Food -2014-V0
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 16:59 Hot Chip - Why Make Sense (2015) [v0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 16:59 Outkast- SouthernPlayalistiCadillacMuzik [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 16:53 Beirut - No No No (Single) (2015) - WEB V0
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 16:52 Jedi_Mind_Tricks-The_Thief_and_the_Fallen-2015-NOiR
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jun 21 16:46 Built To Spill - Untethered Moon (2015) [v0]
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root          4096 Jun 12 22:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Feb  3 03:23 Belle and Sebastian - Girls in Peacetime Want to Dance (2015) MP3 320
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Feb  3 03:19 Caribou - Our Love (2014) [v0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Feb  3 03:06 Bob Dylan - Shadows in the Night (2015) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Jan  2  2015 The Smashing Pumpkins - Monuments to an Elegy - 2014 (WEB V0)
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Dec 26  2014 .sync-pi
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Dec  2  2014 AC-DC - Rock or Bust (2014) [V0]
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Dec  2  2014 The Decemberists_What a Terrible World, What a Beautiful World
drwxr-xr-x   2 ikwyl6 ikwyl6      4096 Nov 28  2014 Wu-Tang Clan - A Better Tomorrow (2014) - WEB V0
```

I want to be able to traverse into each of these directories and list the mp3s in them with added HTML. I know how to do this on a specific directory but doing this:

```
for I in ls Wilco\ -\ Star\ Wars\ \(2015\)\ \[V0\]/*; do echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-src=\"music/$I\">$I</a></li>"; done
```

which gives and which I want to have as the end result for each line of mp3 (showing only 1 line for simplicity):

```
<li><a href="#" data-src="music/Wilco - Star Wars (2015) [V0]/01 - EKG.mp3">Wilco - Star Wars (2015) [V0]/01 - EKG.mp3</a></li>
```

As a start to see how I can obtain getting each directory as a variable for a nested for loop to print each mp3 in each directory, I have tried something like this:

```
for J in ls `ls -alt|head -30`; do
echo $J
done
```

but I run into roadblocks as the output takes each space in each directory name as a new line. Anyone have any ideas how I can do this? How can I get the directory name (which may have characters that may need to be escaped) as a variable for another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your filenames contain space, use while instead of for.
Use ls -At instead of ls -lat to ignore . and ..

```
ls -At|head -30 | while read line; do
echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-src=\"music/${line}.mp3\">$line</a></li>"
done
```

Update: To loop multiple dirs

```
ls -d */ | while read dir; do
   ls -At ${dir} | head -30 | while read line; do
        echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-src=\"music/${dir}${line}.mp3\">line</a></li>"
   done
done
```

Comment: this is what I'm looking for, but what about taking each directory and then going through each mp3 within that dir? Ie: two nested loops..?

Comment: When I change ${dir} to "$dir" it works for me. Otherwise, in the 2nd loop, the ls command receives the $dir variable as separate lines when the folder/dir has spaces in it: 
ls: cannot access Radiohead: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access -: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 2008: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access -: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Scotch: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Mist: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access [V0]/: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

As an example, let's start with these mp3 files:

```
$ ls */*mp3
music1/d e.mp3  music1/d.mp3  music2/a b.mp3  music2/a.mp3
```

There are two safe reliable ways to process file names: one is to use `find` and the other is to use the shell's builtin globbing.  When done properly, and unlike parsing `ls`, both approaches will be safe for any and all file names.  These two approaches are illustrated below.

Also, depending on your final usage, you may need to html-encode the file names.  One way to do that is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873682/short-way-to-escape-html-in-bash).  If you use the file names as part of a URL, you will want [URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755942/possible-to-urlencode-a-variable-in-a-shell-script).

#### Using find

Now, let's make html out of them:

```
$ find . -iname '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'printf "<li><a href=\"#\" data-src=\"%s\">%s</a></li>\n" "$1" "$(basename "$1")"' none {} \;
<li><a href="#" data-src="./music2/a b.mp3">a b.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-src="./music2/a.mp3">a.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-src="./music1/d.mp3">d.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-src="./music1/d e.mp3">d e.mp3</a></li>
```

#### Using bash with extglob

This finds all names of mp3 files in all subdirectories of any depth and makes them into an html list:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ for f in **/*.mp3; do printf '<li><a href="#" data-src="%s">%s</a></li>\n' "$f" "$(basename "$f")"; done
<li><a href="#" data-src="music1/d e.mp3">d e.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-src="music1/d.mp3">d.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-src="music2/a b.mp3">a b.mp3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-src="music2/a.mp3">a.mp3</a></li>
```

Or, written out over multiple lines:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in **/*.mp3
do 
    printf '<li><a href="#" data-src="%s">%s</a></li>\n' "$f" "$(basename "$f")"
done
```

#### Parsing `ls`

Generally, [one should not try to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): with any but the simplest file names, it will fail.  As an example, let's create a file whose name has a tab and a newline:

```
$ touch $'tab\tc\nd'
```

Here is what the output of `ls` looks like:

```
$ ls -At tab*
tab?c?d
```

Observe that `ls` mangled the name, replacing both tab and newline with question marks, `?`.