# How to urlencode data into a URL, with bash or curl

Tags: bash, curl, urlencode

How can a string be urlencoded and embedded into the URL? Please note that I am *not* trying to GET or POST data, so the `-G` and `--data` and `--data-urlencode` options of curl don't seem to do the job.

For example, if you used

```
curl -G http://example.com/foo --data-urlencode "bar=spaced data"
```

that would be functionally equivalent to

```
curl http://example.com/foo?bar=spaced%20data"
```

which is not desired.

I have a string `foo/bar` which must be urlencoded `foo%2fbar` and embedded into the URL.

```
curl http://example.com/api/projects/foo%2fbar/events
```

One hypothetical solution (if I could find something like this) would be to preprocess the data in bash, if there exists some kind of `urlencode` function.

```
DATA=foo/bar
ENCODED=`urlencode $DATA`
curl http://example.com/api/projects/${ENCODED}/events
```

Another hypothetical solution (if I could find something like this) would be some switch in curl, similar to this:

```
curl http://example.com/api/projects/{0}/events --string-urlencode "0=foo/bar"
```

The specific reason I'm looking for an answer to this question is the Gitlab API. For example, [gitlab get single project](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project) `NAMESPACE/PROJECT_NAME` is URL-encoded, eg. `/api/v3/projects/diaspora%2Fdiaspora` (where `/` is represented by `%2F`). Further to this, you can request individual properties in the project, so you end up with a URL such as `http://example.com/projects/diaspora%2Fdiaspora/events`

Although this question is gitlab-specific, I imagine it's generally applicable to REST API's in general, and I'm surprised I can't find a pre-existing answer on stackoverflow or internet search.

Comment: `urlencode $DATA` is going to behave badly if `DATA='*'` (it would expand the glob, encoding a list of filenames); needs to be `"$DATA"`. Also, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html guidelines re: variable names (fourth paragraph): Shell and system tools use all-upper-case names for variables that impact their operation; names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. Since environment variables and shell variables share a namespace, this applies to regular (non-exported) names as well.

Comment: BTW, did you try the answer by Orwellophile in the not-quite-dupe-but-closely-related question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10660730/14122?

Comment: Seems pretty close to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755942/possible-to-urlencode-a-variable-in-a-shell-script has among others also a perl solution that you can craft into a function.

Comment: So far yes, I'm able to find an implementation of `urlencode()` (found [here](https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649)) that can be pasted into a bash script. It's a solution, but I'm doubtful it's the best solution.

Comment: this answer is a one liner for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10797966/1839558

Answer (score 14):

The `urlencode` function you propose is easy enough to implement:

```
urlencode() {
  python -c 'import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])' \
    "$1" "$urlencode_safe"
}
```

...used as:

```
data=foo/bar
encoded=$(urlencode "$data")
curl "http://example.com/api/projects/${encoded}/events"
```

If you want to have some characters which are passed through literally -- in many use cases, this is desired for `/`s -- instead use:

```
encoded=$(urlencode_safe='/' urlencode "$data")
```

Comment: FWIW, if you happen to have `jq` installed, you can use the slightly shorter `printf %s "$1" | jq -s -R -r @uri`

Comment: Nice trick; a bit shorter (`-s` doesn't appear necessary, but I'm not sure): `jq -R -r @uri <<<"$1"`

Comment: @rici great comment. This should be a separate answer!

Comment: Shorter still (if that's what you want) combine `-R -r` to `-Rr`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)'s comment
on the accepted answer (which has more upvotes than the answer itself), we may create the function `ue` (short for `urlencode`, but you may call it as you wish) on top of `jq` and make it read from stdin or from an argument:

```bash
ue() {local in=$1; if [ -z "$in" ]; then read in; fi; echo $in|jq -sRr '@uri'}
```

```bash
echo "https://example.com/$(ue "some part")/?date=$(date|ue)"
```

One-liner, no Python, just `jq`, plain and simple...

Answer (score 0):

One-liner in Python3:

```
python -c "from urllib.parse import quote; print(quote(input('Type here: ')))"
```